# Detecting a click on a line drawn in a UIView

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am working on a project management system and I am doing a tree diagram where every node is a NSView and connections between them are also NSView. Is there any easy way to check if an NSView with a drawn line is clicked? This is the source of the VTConnection NSView. I am trying to get the color of the clicked point but no success as yet. The other idea is to use 4 linear equations :

```
#import "VTConnection.h"
#import "VTNodeAbstract.h"

@implementation VTConnection


-(void)drawMe {

}

-(struct VTConnectionStructORM) bluePrint {
    VTConnectionStructORM conn;

    conn.connection_id = self.connection_id;
    conn.start_pos_x = self.start_pos.x;
    conn.start_pos_y = self.start_pos.y;
    conn.end_pos_x = self.end_pos.x;
    conn.end_pos_y = self.end_pos.y;

    return conn;
}

-(void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    /*
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[NSColor grayColor].CGColor];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];*/

    [[NSColor clearColor] set];
    [self.layer setOpaque:NO];
    // NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

    // return;
    // get the initial context
    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

    // save the current state, as we'll overwrite this
    // CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [[NSColor grayColor] set];
    // draw stuff
    NSPoint outerStart = [self convertPoint:self.start_pos fromView:[self superview]];
    NSPoint outerEnd = [self convertPoint:self.end_pos fromView:[self superview]];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, outerStart.x, outerStart.y);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, outerEnd.x, outerEnd.y);

    // do the actual drawing
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    // [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    // NSLog(@" drawing connection %@ --> %@", NSStringFromPoint(self.start_pos), NSStringFromPoint(self.end_pos));
}

-(id) initWithORM:(NSDictionary *) dict {
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        self.connection_id = [dict[@"connection"] intValue];

        self.start_pos = NSMakePoint([dict[@"start_pos_x"] floatValue], [dict[@"start_pos_y"] floatValue]);
        self.end_pos = NSMakePoint([dict[@"end_pos_x"] floatValue], [dict[@"end_pos_y"] floatValue]);
    }

    self.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return self;
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@" click on connection %@", theEvent);

    NSBitmapImageRep *test = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:self.frame];

    NSPoint pointInMyFrame = [self convertPoint:theEvent.locationInWindow fromView:[self superview]];

    NSLog(@" color %f %f" , pointInMyFrame.x ,pointInMyFrame.y);
    NSLog(@" color %@",[test colorAtX:(int)pointInMyFrame.x y:(int)pointInMyFrame.y]);
}

-(void) redrawWithPoints:(NSPoint )A B:(NSPoint)B {
    NSRect rect;

    if (A.x > B.x) {
        rect.origin.x = B.x;
        self.start_pos = B;
        self.end_pos = A;
    } else {
        rect.origin.x = A.x;
        self.start_pos = A;
        self.end_pos = B;
    }

    if (A.y > B.y) {
        rect.origin.y = B.y;
    } else {
        rect.origin.y = A.y;
    }

    rect.size.width = abs(A.x-B.x);
    rect.size.height = abs(A.y-B.y);

    self.frame = rect;

    // [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect];
}

-(BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isOpaque {
    // If the background color is opaque, return YES
    // otherwise, return NO
    return NO;
}

-(NSString *) description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ connection %i", [self class], self.connection_id];
}

@end
```

the diagram image 
http://iccode.co.uk/vt/sof/diagram.png

Comment: If the question says `UIView` why did you add the `osx` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `CGPath`?. There is `CGPathContainsPoint` function that solves your issue.

**UPD:**

```
CGContextRef ctx = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
NSPoint outerStart = [self convertPoint:self.start_pos fromView:[self superview]];
NSPoint outerEnd = [self convertPoint:self.end_pos fromView:[self superview]];
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, outerStart.x, outerStart.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, outerEnd.x, outerEnd.y);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Code above draws line using `CGPath`. You may store `path` value and use it as parameter for `CGPathContainsPoint` function.

Comment: could you give me an example how should i use it, i am new to that kind of development

Answer (score 0):

You should draw your line by creating CGPath, save it somewhere (or, reconstruct when you checking the touch location) and after that use CGPathContainsPoint function.
However, more logical would be to construct the path which contains wider area since it would be almost impossible to hit directly into one-point thick path with your finger.